# Using <> in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

The question is to find the employee last names for employees who do not have a child of the same sex as themselves.

My code is :

```
SELECT E.Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE E, DEPENDENT D
WHERE E.Ssn = D.Essn 
AND E.Sex <> D.Sex
```

But I've learned that it is a bad practice to use <>. When I used <> I get multiple names as output.

```
Smith
Smith
Wong
Wong
Wallace
```

Is there an alternate way of doing this using NOT IN clause?

Comment: From comments it seems like you might want to limit to people that have children, but not children of the same sex as themselves?  If that's the case you should re-word your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT E.Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM DEPENDENT D
                  WHERE E.Ssn = D.Essn 
                    AND E.Sex = D.Sex
                    AND D.Relationship IN ('Son','Daughter')
                 )
```

This will only return records from the `EMPLOYEE` table, so no multiple records returned.

Edit: Noticed the relationship options included 'spouse'.

Comment: The answer should return only Smith and Wong from my understanding. This code will return English, Narayan, Borg, Wallace, Jabber, Zelaya.

Comment: @Nocturnal They meet the criteria of not having a child of the same sex, why wouldn't they be included?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT E.Lname 
  FROM EMPLOYEE E, DEPENDENT D
  WHERE E.Ssn = D.Essn 
    AND D.Relationship IN ("Son", "Daughter")
    AND E.Sex = D.Sex
  GROUP BY E.Ssn
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here? From what I understand you are checking for the dependents with the same sex not the opposite sex.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Cartesian product from the query, join use left join to not repeat entries.
i.e.

```
SELECT E.Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT D
ON E.Ssn = D.Essn 
WHERE E.Sex <> D.Sex
```

**NOTE** Query would give duplicate last name as long as multiple employee has same last name.if unique last name is required then try below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(E.Lname) 
FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT D
ON E.Ssn = D.Essn 
WHERE E.Sex <> D.Sex
```

Comment: query must give you same  last name entry twice as long as you have two or more employees having same last name.If you want unique last name use distinct function to do that

Comment: This is identical to OP's original query. The `LEFT JOIN` is transformed to an `INNER JOIN` due to the criteria in the `WHERE` clause, and though OP was using deprecated syntax for a join, the logic is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(EMPLOYEE.Lname) FROM DEPENDENT LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON DEPENDENT.Essn=EMPLOYEE.Ssn WHERE (DEPENDENT.Sex <> EMPLOYEE.Sex) AND DEPENDENT.Relationship IN ('Daughter','Son');
```

Comment: You cannot return a spouse. Wallace only has a spouse, not kids.

Comment: @Nocturnal add AND DEPENDENT.Relationship IN ('Daughter','Son') to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Find the a list of employees who have a child with the same sex as them and then exclude them from the list of all those who have a child.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Lname
FROM Employee A
INNER JOIN Dependent B
on A.Ssn = B.essn
Where B.Relationship in ('Son', 'Daughter')
    AND A.Ssn not in (
        SELECT AA.ssn
        FROM Employee AA
        INNER JOIN Dependent BB
        on AA.Ssn = BB.essn
        Where BB.Relationship in ('Son', 'Daughter')
            And AA.Sex = BB.Sex
        )
```